# Why does my Structured Stream doesn't continue after first couple of messages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

For my spark 2.1.1 and Kafka 0.10.2.1 strcutured stream example, i am able to work my way through `foreach` sink. My stream source is configured to push 2 messages every 10 seconds.

I see that first couple of messages pass through just fine through the `foreach` sink (the open-process-close) constructs. However, after the first push, the process doesn't read from queue anymore ?

Any ideas ?

```
val stream = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka10.broker")
  .option("subscribe", src_topic)
  .load()

val df = stream.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")

  .select(functions.from_json(StringToColumn(StringContext.apply("json")).$(), txnSchema).as("data"))
          .select("data.*")
```

Writer implementation:

```
 val writer = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
      /*
      Prepare Hbase connection
      Prepare Kafka Producer
      */
        true
      }

     override def process(row: Row) = {
         try {
         /*
            Do biz logic
            get data from hbase
            at the end, write to a kafka queue
         */
         }
         catch {
            case tt: Throwable => {
            rlog("Something else wierd happened.")
            }
         }
      }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {
    println("-------------------------------In close now. checking whether it was called due to soem error")
    if(errorOrNull != null)
      errorOrNull .printStackTrace()

    println("-------------------------------Closing hbase Connection")
    //closing hbase connections

    println("-------------------------------Closing Kafka connection now")
    // closing kafka producer object

   // Other cleanup
    println("-------------------------------All done. Exiting now.")
  }
}
```

During my business logic processing, I need to convert the data from HBase to a data frame for further processing.  My attempts to do that fail. Another gent mentioned that it's not "allowed " since that part is running on executors.

What's the recommendation on that ?

Comment: Could you use `writeStream.format("console")` to debug? Just to rule out ForeachWriter

Comment: Tried that, the plain console sink works just fine. My business logic is what is added, the hbase connectivity, the kafka message write etc are the keys besides the processing bit. Wondering whats interfering with stream processing !!

Comment: Then it's probably because you catch exception in `process` method. I don't know why you did it. But it hides all possible exceptions including errors in your DataFrame.

Comment: If _"the plain console sink works just fine"_, I'd add one feature at a time and see what breaks the stream. Start with connecting to the external datasources.

Comment: That Idea helped me pin point the root cause of behaviour, "hbase connection closure was the one."   thanks guys.